# Developing an Open-Source Packet Filtering and Application Firewall for final year project

Tags: firewall

I have decided build an open source firewall in linux environment. I have exactly one year to complete this project. The firewall will be a stateful packet filtering firewall working at network, transport and application layers. I would also be provided log analysis features.

Some of the network layer features are as follows:

1. Stateful Packet Inspection: Tracking each connection and filtering packets by breaking them into headers and data.
2. Port-scan detection
3. DoS and DDoS Protection
4. SYN/ICMP Flood Protection
5. Anti-spoofing Protection

For application layer features I may decide to provide antivirus and antispam filters.

What I want to know is whether this is a good enough project or put in other words, is it a worthwhile project to undertake?

Thanx in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with existing packages, such as iptables?

Antivirus/antispam functionality is usually provided by separate packages and is not a part of the firewall. This is not the Windows world, where there is one "security suite". In Linux, you run a firewall; you run a separate antivirus scanner (or not), and you run an antispam filter plugin on your MTA.

I think writing a new system from scratch is relatively pointless, unless you have already studied the existing alternatives in depth and concluded all of them are architecturally lacking and can not be salvaged. To do something worthwhile, it would be much better to identify something an existing popular package lacks, and then contribute that feature to the package.

Comment: Here is the status of existing firewalls in terms of ipv6 support:

1. pfsense: no ipv6 support (under development)
2. m0n0wall : no ipv6 support (under development)
3. ipcop: no ipv6 support
4. firestarter: no ipv6 support

So should I volunteer to contribute in one of these projects or make my own DPI firewall with ipv6 support?

Comment: Personally I think contributing to an existing, widely used project will have larger impact, as well as letting you work on the new parts (IPv6 support) instead of writing the whole thing.